# Why is my button not working

Tags: java, web-services, ssl

I have just deployed a web project on WAS 7.0.0.15. 
In a JSP page a button is not working for some users and working for others. 
I have tried a mix of javascript and java for all the validations and such. And the javascipt and the cookies too, are working for the users who faced the issue.
I saw the error logs and there are some repetitive SSL errors but I cannot comprehend what they mean. 
Seems like the project blew up in my face and I cant for the life of me figure out what the hell is going on.

The SSL error come in two pairs:

The 1st one containing the 3 errors below:

> com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContent$SSLCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:643)
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1049)

This above error pair occured twice in the logs

The 2nd pair contains the 5 errors below:

> com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLHandshakeIOCallback.complete(SSLHandshakeIOCallback.java:87)
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:1066)
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:413)
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInboundPostHandshake(SSLConnectionLink.java:717)
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1049)

The above error pair occured thrice in the logs

Can you please tell me why the buttons aren't working and if the server is related to errors in any way, How can I undo it.
I have the following up until now 
"Cookies arent disabled"
"Global setting have been copied as a security domain"

Comment: please add some code and the line numbers may also help..

Comment: Neither of those "errors" include the actual exception and its message.